# Printing one fewer "*" per line using while loops in C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Printing one less star per line after user specifies initial number using while loops.

This is a school project so I'm not asking you to answer just need to be pointed in the right direction.

```
int main() {
    int number;
    int stars;
    char st = '*'; //using char to setup the "*"

    printf("please enter a positive number:");
    scanf("%d", &stars);

    while (stars > 0) {
        stars = (char) st; //tryin to convert number eneter to a char
        stars = stars - 1;
        printf("%c \n", stars);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have lost my way, should I be converting integers to chars or?

Comment: This program doesn't print _any_ stars.  So you want to print one less than zero stars.

Comment: For a start, you have overwritten the loop control variable with `stars = (char) st;`.

Comment: Your clarification makes less sense than your question.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild stab at what you _might_ be asking.  The user enters "5", so you print 5 stars on the first line, 4 stars on the next line, then 3, 2, 1...  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Pointing in the right direction? There are telltales in the code that say you spent 5 minutes on this at most. Sit, down, draw in a breath and spend some quality time on it. That's a better way.

Comment: Write a C program that asks the user to enter a positive integer greater than 1, and prints that number of stars on the first line, then 1 less on the second line and so on until 1 star is reached.

Comment: Okay, in that case I think you should start by writing a program that prints one single line of stars, based on the number the user typed in.  Once you are able to do that, then you can figure out how to do the rest.

Comment: You reset `stars` to the value of `st` on each iteration...you don't change `st`.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

- read the umber of stars from the user (you got this almost right, you should check that `scanf()` returns 1.
- use a `for` loop and decrement `star` and stop at `0`.
- in the loop, write another loop that prints `star` copies of `*` and a newline
- that's it! return 0.

Answer (score 0):

What you have already is that inside the `while` loop your variable stars is decreasing... so if you enter `10` the variable `stars` will be `10`, `9`, `8`, ..., until it's `0`... Now let's think carefully, when your variable `stars` is equal to `10` you want to print ten stars, right? How do you do it? **The answer is with another loop**, for example with a `for` loop or another `while` loop like you did to iterate your variable stars from the input of the user to `0`, so it's basically doing the same thing that you did already.

Here's a hint, instead of `printf("%c \n", stars)` (which actually **prints the character whose ASCII code is equal to `stars`**) you should have `printf("%c", st)` or `printf("%c", '*')` directly, because you need to print the character `*` and you should do this a `stars` number of times inside the while loop **and then print a new line** at the end of that loop.

In short:

- Your first step is right, you have to iterate trough the users input to `0` and you are actually doing that.
- When the value of `starts = i` you have to print `i` times `*` and you do that with another loop, just like you've done already, and then print a new line at the end of each iteration in that loop.

Comment: Answering a person's homework does not help that person learn how to think like a programmer.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, is there something bad with my explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You have got a couple of problems as far as I can see:

1. You seem to be trying to create a "row" of stars via your `stars = (char) st;` line, but that doesn't work like that: What you are really doing there is assigning the ASCII value of the star (which is 42) to the `stars` variable.
2. This causes another problem, namely that your `while` loop never finishes because at each iteration, even though you subtracted 1 from 42, you re-assign 42 to your `stars` variable.
3. Instead of printing the `st` variable (the star character), you are printing the `stars` variable, which I believe you are supposed to be using to count the number of stars yet to be printed.
4. Finally, you are printing space and newline characters `" \n"` after each star instead of keeping all stars on the same line. You can solve this by removing those characters from the existing print statement and using another print statement at the end of the loop (or leave that out for now until you got the rest working).

I hope that helps somewhat, let me know if you need further information.

**EDIT:**

To help you debugging your programs, you can simply add some print statements between your other statements to see what the values of your variables look like while the program executes... which then might give you hints about what is going wrong. For example, to see how the `stars` variable is changing in each loop iteration, use `printf("stars = %d\n", stars);` inside the `while` loop.  Of course, this will bugger up your star-printing, but once the program behaves itself, you can remove those debug print statements.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the following. Remove these statements

```
   while (stars > 0) {
        stars = (char) st; //tryin to convert number eneter to a char
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        stars = stars - 1;
        printf("%c \n", stars);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
```

You have to output the character `st`. The variable `starts` is used as a count for the iterations of the loop.

Inside the loop before the statement

```
    stars = stars - 1;
```

place a for loop that will output exactly `starts` times the character `st`.

And remove this declaration

```
int number;
```

because the variable `number` is not used in the code.

That is all.:)

Comment: would the stars times st literally be 'stars * st' printf ("%c", st);

Comment: @FinnHowieson This is a correct statement. You need to place it inside a for loop that in turn will be in the current while loop.

Comment: thanks alot, and the condition for the second while loop should be (st == stars) ?

Comment: @FinnHowieson The second for loop can look like for ( int I = 0; I < stars; I++ ) printf( "%c", st ); After the loop you need to output the new line character printf( "\n" );